# SQL triple join on the same table is slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table shown below

```
 CREATE TABLE `xcpRush2_SandraTriplets` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idConceptStart` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idConceptLink` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idConceptTarget` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `flag` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_name` (`idConceptStart`,`idConceptLink`,`idConceptTarget`),
  KEY `idConceptStart` (`idConceptStart`,`idConceptLink`,`idConceptTarget`),
  KEY `idConceptStart_4` (`idConceptStart`),
  KEY `idConceptTarget` (`idConceptTarget`),
  KEY `idConceptLink` (`idConceptLink`,`idConceptTarget`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Data will look like in db fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ejXP7qgvwNqAZeuaN3DFNz/3

As you can see it is fully indexed on on several column.

On my table I have about 800k idConceptStart satisfying the condition of having

```
idConceptLink = 5 idConceptTarget = 14500 AND
idConceptLink = 3 idConceptLink = 14504 AND
idConceptLink = 12 idConceptLink = 11
```

When I execute this query

```
SELECT * FROM  xcpRush2_SandraTriplets l    
   JOIN  xcpRush2_SandraTriplets link1 ON link1.idConceptStart = l.idConceptStart  
   JOIN  xcpRush2_SandraTriplets link2 ON link2.idConceptStart = link1.idConceptStart

    WHERE 
       l.idConceptLink = 5  AND 
       l.idConceptTarget = 14500 AND 
       l.flag != 1 AND 

       link2.flag != 1 AND 
       link2.idConceptLink = 3 AND 
       link2.idConceptTarget = 14504 AND 

       link1.flag != 1 AND 
       link1.idConceptTarget = 12 AND 
       l.idConceptLink = 11  

    ORDER BY l.idConceptStart DESC  LIMIT 10
```

Here is the SQL Explain
[image: SQL Explain]

The query takes about 30 seconds (!) to render

But if I remove this (and only this)

```
 link2.idConceptLink = 3 AND link2.idConceptTarget =14504
```

then the query takes 20 milliseconds to render

```
    SELECT * FROM  xcpRush2_SandraTriplets l    
   JOIN  xcpRush2_SandraTriplets link1 ON link1.idConceptStart = l.idConceptStart  
   JOIN  xcpRush2_SandraTriplets link2 ON link2.idConceptStart = l.idConceptStart 
   WHERE 
      l.idConceptLink = 5 AND 
      l.idConceptTarget = 14500 AND 
      l.flag != 1  AND 

      link2.flag != 1 AND       

      link1.flag != 1 AND 
      link1.idConceptTarget = 12 AND 
      link1.idConceptLink = 11  

    ORDER BY l.idConceptStart DESC  LIMIT 10
```

[image: SQL Explain]

I'm puzzled because the table is indexed on `idConceptLink`,`idConceptTarget` and each of those query taken separately are very fast to render < 20 ms

Also every `idConceptLink`,`idConceptTarget` pairs in the query are all returning a heavy number of rows (not only link2.idConceptLink = 3 AND link2.idConceptTarget =14504)

Could you help me identifying the bottle neck ?

**Edit**

After more findings in the comments the issue seems to be on the ORDER BY. Depending if I join on l.idConceptStart or link1.idConceptStart or link2.idConceptStart the query is slow. On my actual case ORDER BY *link2.idConceptStart* is slow.

The index structure is the following

```
CREATE TABLE `xcpRush2_SandraTriplets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idConceptStart` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idConceptLink` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idConceptTarget` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `flag` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_name` (`idConceptStart`,`idConceptLink`,`idConceptTarget`),
  KEY `idConceptStart` (`idConceptStart`),
  KEY `idConceptTarget` (`idConceptTarget`),
  KEY `idConceptLink` (`idConceptLink`,`idConceptTarget`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5747878 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Index are

```
xcprush2_sandratriplets 0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   5207892 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xcprush2_sandratriplets 0   idx_name    1   idConceptStart  A   1243366 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xcprush2_sandratriplets 0   idx_name    2   idConceptLink   A   5207936 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xcprush2_sandratriplets 0   idx_name    3   idConceptTarget A   5207936 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xcprush2_sandratriplets 1   idConceptStart  1   idConceptStart  A   1122352 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xcprush2_sandratriplets 1   idConceptTarget 1   idConceptTarget A   123870  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xcprush2_sandratriplets 1   idConceptLink   1   idConceptLink   A   5   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
xcprush2_sandratriplets 1   idConceptLink   2   idConceptTarget A   154480  NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

[image: Indexes]

The query is **slow** when I do

```
 SELECT  l.idConceptStart, l.idConceptLink, l.`idConceptTarget` FROM  xcpRush2_SandraTriplets l  JOIN  xcpRush2_SandraTriplets link1 ON link1.idConceptStart = l.idConceptStart  JOIN  xcpRush2_SandraTriplets link2 ON link2.idConceptStart = l.idConceptStart 
    WHERE l.idConceptLink = 5  
    AND l.idConceptTarget = 14500
    AND l.flag != 1 
     AND link1.flag != 1 AND 
            link1.idConceptTarget =14504 AND link1.idConceptLink = 3 AND link2.flag != 1 AND 
            link2.idConceptTarget =12 AND link2.idConceptLink = 11  ORDER BY  link2.idConceptStart DESC  LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```

Here is the EXPLAIN structure

```
1   SIMPLE  link1   NULL    ref idx_name,idConceptStart,idConceptTarget,idConceptLink   idConceptTarget 4   const   1611256 18.00   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  l   NULL    eq_ref  idx_name,idConceptStart,idConceptTarget,idConceptLink   idx_name    12  sandra.link1.idConceptStart,const,const 1   90.00   Using where
1   SIMPLE  link2   NULL    eq_ref  idx_name,idConceptStart,idConceptTarget,idConceptLink   idx_name    12  sandra.link1.idConceptStart,const,const 1   90.00   Using where
```

[image: Slow explain]

The query is **fast** when I do

```
SELECT  l.idConceptStart, l.idConceptLink, l.`idConceptTarget` FROM  xcpRush2_SandraTriplets l  JOIN  xcpRush2_SandraTriplets link1 ON link1.idConceptStart = l.idConceptStart  JOIN  xcpRush2_SandraTriplets link2 ON link2.idConceptStart = l.idConceptStart 
    WHERE l.idConceptLink = 5  
    AND l.idConceptTarget = 14500
    AND l.flag != 1 
     AND link1.flag != 1 AND 
            link1.idConceptTarget =14504 AND link1.idConceptLink = 3 AND link2.flag != 1 AND 
            link2.idConceptTarget =12 AND link2.idConceptLink = 11  ORDER BY  l.idConceptStart DESC  LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```

Here is the EXPLAIN structure

```
   1    SIMPLE  l   NULL    index   idx_name,idConceptStart,idConceptTarget,idConceptLink   idConceptStart  4   NULL    13036   3.08    Using where
1   SIMPLE  link1   NULL    eq_ref  idx_name,idConceptStart,idConceptTarget,idConceptLink   idx_name    12  sandra.l.idConceptStart,const,const 1   90.00   Using where
1   SIMPLE  link2   NULL    eq_ref  idx_name,idConceptStart,idConceptTarget,idConceptLink   idx_name    12  sandra.l.idConceptStart,const,const 1   90.00   Using where
```

[image: fastExplain]

Edit 2

the optimal table to sort seems to be random. Now that I run the same query few hours laters (some insert occurred) but using the same query the structure of solving the key order changed. The fast query becomes the slow one and the slow one become the fast one. If I ORDER BY l.idConceptStart the following explain

[image: explain edit 2]

the table resolution order for keys seems to be random. I'm completely lost. In the end the only think I need is to get last database entry first

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for hints with provide data table as text.. using Images as data example is not good we can't easy reproduce from images.

Comment: How long does the query take without the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: If you change `idConceptLink` index to become `(idConceptLink, idConceptTarget, idConceptStart)` does it reduce number of rows in EXPLAIN?

Comment: "How long does the query take without the ORDER BY?" Wow It is very fast under 1ms why ?

Comment: ORDER BY l.idConceptStart DESC - requires processing to get the DESCending order and will be influenced by number of ROWS in the table contributing to longer duration as rows are added.  How many rows are in the table?

Comment: "If you change idConceptLink index to become (idConceptLink, idConceptTarget, idConceptStart) does it reduce number of rows in EXPLAIN? " No it doesn't help

Comment: There are 6 mio rows in the table

Comment: @WilsonHauck interestingly if I ORDER BY link2.idConceptStart then the query is super fast. I don't know exactly why since the value is strictly equal

Comment: Please post the CURRENT QUERY and EXPLAIN for the two queries you are researching.  Also post CURRENT TEXT results of SHOW INDEX FROM xcpRush2_SandraTriplets; please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I created a db-fiddle for it https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ejXP7qgvwNqAZeuaN3DFNz/3

Comment: You need to run an Explain Plan on the original version of the query, and the version where you removed the one condition, and then compare them.  The result should be obvious, it is possible that removing the condition causes it to do a tablespace scan instead of an index scan, and maybe that makes it faster?  Anyway, you'll be able to see the difference in the different Explain Plans.

Comment: Your db-fiddle can not possibly be near your 6 mio rows of data for TWO reasons. 1) db-fiddle is MISSING the DESC part of ORDER BY.  2) The counts reported by SHOW INDEX FROM will be nothing like your real table results.  Again ... Please post the CURRENT QUERY and EXPLAIN for the two queries you are researching. Also post CURRENT TEXT results of SHOW INDEX FROM xcpRush2_SandraTriplets; please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I updated the original post according to your requests.

Comment: Answer posted with my conclusions after reviewing additional information posted about 4 hours ago.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"fully indexed" -- No.  You have a few indexes, including some redundant ones.

This may be the optimal index for your query:

```
INDEX(link, target, start)
```

Let's talk about `flag`.  How many different values does it have?  If only 2 (say, 0 an 1), then change to `flag = 0` instead of `flag != 1`.  The Optimizer is better at working with `=` tests than `!=`.  And change to `INDEX(link, target, flag, start)`.

What percentage of rows have flag=1?  This could lead to some more thoughts.

You have `UNIQUE` key, plus a surrogate `id`?  Do you reference `id` from any other table?  If not, get rid of it, and promote the `UNIQUE` to `PRIMARY KEY`.  But at that point, I would want the columns in that PK to be rearranged to match my suggestion.

Some rules for building indexes:

- Put columns tested with `=` first (`link` and `target`, in either order)
- It is better to have the index *completely* handle the `WHERE` (`!=` is stopping that) if you want it to also include the `ORDER BY` column(s).  This is especially true if there is also a `LIMIT`.
- `UNIQUE(a,b,c)` precludes the need for `INDEX(a,b,c)`
- `INDEX(a,b)` precludes the need for `INDEX(a)`.
- More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: Yes the performance gain is outstanding !
Thanks a lot

As for today they all 0 but for some db instance it's less than 1%
But potentially a flag can be any concept id (just like start link and target)

`Put columns tested with = first ` OK

`There's not much use in mixing WHERE columns and ORDER BY columns unless the index completely handles the WHERE ` I don't understand that statement

`Unless the index completely handles both the WHERE and ORDER BY,[...] LIMIT.`
What does it means practicaly ?

`INDEX(a,b) precludes the need for INDEX(a).` I might read the doc to get it

Answer (score 0):

By using 
    ORDER BY  l.idConceptStart DESC 
rather than
    ORDER BY  link2.idConceptStart DESC
you were able to avoid per EXPLAIN the temp storage and filesort 
and the ROWS to be accessed were significantly reduced.

View my profile, Network profile for contact info.

Comment: "to avoid per EXPLAIN the temp storage and filesort"
How can I predict that ? It seems pretty random to me (updated my profile as well)

Comment: @ShabanShaame You find them with EXPLAIN and when found, search for mysql avoid temporary AND mysql avoid filesort for ideas.  Key to your solution involved, A) only retrieving the columns of data needed rather than * ( * should rarely be used) AND B) using the l.idConceptStart index rather than link2 which is far-removed compared to the l. link.  If I have been helpful, please consider upvote and accept.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not solved. The issue appears to be random. Now that I run the query again the fast query is slow and the slow one is fast.

It looks like the explain takes the first table (in this case the same) in different order (depending on the it's mood)

Comment: Try STRAIGHT JOIN for more predictability.

Comment: @ShabanShaame Try STRAIGHT JOIN or STRAIGHT_JOIN for more predictability.  There are tutorials available for both, search for mysql straight join tutorial with examples  OR  mysql straight_join tutorial with examples for information.  Would like to Skype TALK with you, if possible.  I am in UTC -6 hours.